# Is it really necessary manage event handler by ourselves?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Recently I read **John Resig**'s book **Secrets of Javascript Ninja**, in the chapter about
element event, he write:

> For a number of reasons, it would be advantageous to not bind event
> handlers directly to  elements.

So in his next code, he define custom `addEvent` ,`detachevent`, `dispatcher` ,`triggerevent` method, and store event handler into a cache queue and so on.

Despite the browser compatibility issue, is there any other reason don't bind event handler directly to element?

Comment: one situation where I may prefer is if I want to add the handler to a lot of element in a page like a edit button handler in a listing page or 50 items

Comment: Whether to add listeners to elements or "delegate" to parent elements has nothing to do with (unspecified) browser comparability issues. It has to do with application design, e.g. it might be advantageous (simpler logic, easier to maintain, etc.)  to add a single listener to a table that handles all click events on the table rather than adding a listener to every cell that needs one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason to use this model will be when you are dealing with dynamic elements.

If you want to attach the handlers to the element itself after the creation of the each element you need to attach the handler to it, but I prefer to make use of event delegation and register the handler to an element which will be always there and then filter the target element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is given in the later part in the same section. I am just copying it for reference:

■ The Event instance is fixed up.

■ The function context is set to the target element.

■ The Event instance is passed to the handler as its sole argument.

■ The event handlers will always be executed in the order in which they were bound.

Besides you have cleaner control over the removal of handlers too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to keep track of your event listeners if you keep a reference to each of them and their info. It gives you some extra control; now it's up to you to choose when you need to use it.